# One-to-many table join in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a spatial layer (shapefile) that has one row for each of one of the attributes in the table (representing management units). I also have a non-spatial CSV file that has wildlife inventory data for each of these management units. The problem is that there are multiple lines of inventory data (one for each year) for the management units in the CSV file, so when I do a join in QGIS only one line of inventory data is joined with the spatial layer and the others are ignored.

Is this possible in QGIS?

I think in ArcMap this is referred to as a one-to-many joins.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is possible and the feature is called relations.

You have to setup the relation between the two layers in Project -> Properties -> Relations

Then you can configure the forms accordingly.

You can read up on the feature here: http://blog.vitu.ch/10112013-1201/qgis-relations